# Ignored tag preferences link doesn't show me any tag options

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, preferences

When your settings are set to not show ignored tags, you see something like this at the bottom:

> Hiding questions because of your [Ignored Tags preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) for tags:
>
> [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)

However, the page linked to doesn't have my "Ignored Tags preferences" nor anything to do with tags at all. The options are: "Keyboard shortcuts", "Navigation", "Custom Question Lists" (on SO, MSO, MSE), "Advertisements" (with Reduce Ads privilege), "Personalized predictions".

It should lead somewhere I can change my ignored tags preferences (currently the only place where this can be done is the sidebar).

Comment: Should be a "Tag Watching & Ignoring" link in the sidebar of the preferences page - ignored tag preferences are there.

Comment: @Shog9 Well I missed it the first time I looked, but the link should be directly to it, not my preferences page in general.

Comment: Yeah, they made breaking change to the URL and forgot to change old links. Link should be: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the footer now links to /users/tag-notifications/current.

Thanks for reporting this, and hat-tip to the Shadow Wizard for digging up the correct link!